# adding custom vaildation error in antd form rules

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my form if I select max countries list is more than 2 then I need to set error message. Please help me to setup custom errors in antd. I gave rules, max: 2, I am not getting.

My goal is if count field is grearthan 2 then I need to display error message.

link: [Code Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/other-form-controls-antd-4-16-13-forked-we4fw?file=/index.js:0-2961)

logic:

```
const handleCount = () => {
    if (count > 2) {
      throw new Error("Max colleges list [2] exceeded ")
    }
  }
```

jsx logic :

```
      <Form.Item
          rules={[
            {
              validator: {handleCount}
            },
          ]}
        >
          {collegesSelectedList.map((college) => (
            <ul style={{listStyleType: "none", padding: "0px"}}>
              <li key={college}>
                {count++}.{college}
                <Button
                  size="small"
                  onClick={() => handleRemoveList(college)}
                  icon={<DeleteOutlined />}
                  danger
                />
              </li>
            </ul>
          ))}
        </Form.Item>
```

screen:
[image]